# What's the difference between () and [] in regular expression patterns?

Tags: regex

What is the difference between encasing part of a regular expression in () (parentheses) and doing it in [] (square brackets)?

How does this:

```
[a-z0-9]
```

differ from this:

```
(a-z0-9)
```

?

Comment: Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`[]` denotes a character class. `()` denotes a capturing group.

`[a-z0-9]` -- One character that is in the range of `a-z` OR `0-9`

`(a-z0-9)` -- Explicit capture of `a-z0-9`. No ranges.

`a` -- Can be captured by `[a-z0-9]`.

`a-z0-9` -- Can be captured by `(a-z0-9)` and then can be referenced in a replacement and/or later in the expression.

Comment: can you please tell why these two are different `/[\s+]?,[\s+]?/` vs `/(\s+)?,(\s+)?/`

Comment: The first has characters in a character class, the second uses a capturing group. Those expressions are actually completely different. The first will match 0 or 1 whitespace character OR a +, followed by a comma, followed by 0 or 1 whitespace character OR a +. The latter will match 0 or more whitespace characters followed by a comma, followed by 0 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: So, basically, if you have a string as follows: `var myStr = '  ,    '`, the first expression will NOT match, whereas the second one will. If you have another string as follows: `var myOtherStr = '+,'`, it will match the first expression but not the second.

Comment: I used JS as my example language, but the concept is how most regular expressions will work. http://www.regular-expressions.info is a great resource if you're trying to learn about regular expressions. =)

Comment: but in js `+` is special regex character...why would it get matched!?

Comment: A `+` is a special character in pretty much any flavor of regex. However, when inside of a character group (a set of characters inside of `[]`), the `+` is matched as a regular character instead.

Comment: so if i want this, then it's not possible..`[a+]`. Thanks for pointing that out i'd have not guessed at all that + inside brackets is just plus.

Comment: If you're looking to match 'a+', you want to escape the `+` as such: `\+`. That will tell the parser to look for a '+'.

Comment: no no as you told me and i confirmed that **a+** in `[a+]` is actually a and +. Not aaaaaa....! So if i wanted aaaaaa... in [] what would i do. This: `[(?:a+)]`.?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, then. If I was looking for a bunch of 'a's in a row, I'd simply use `a+`.

Answer (score 33):

`(…)` is a [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that groups the contents like in math; `(a-z0-9)` is the grouped sequence of `a-z0-9`. Groups are particularly used with [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) that allow the preceding expression to be repeated as a whole: `a*b*` matches any number of `a`’s followed by any number of `b`’s, e.g. `a`, `aaab`, `bbbbb`, etc.; in contrast to that, `(ab)*` matches any number of `ab`’s, e.g. `ab`, `abababab`, etc.

`[…]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that describes the options for one single character; `[a-z0-9]` describes one single character that can be of the range `a`–`z` or `0`–`9`.

Answer (score 27):

The `[]` construct in a regex is essentially shorthand for an `|` on all of the contents.  For example `[abc]` matches a, b or c.   Additionally the `-` character has special meaning inside of a `[]`.  It provides a range construct.  The regex `[a-z]` will match any letter a through z.

The `()` construct is a grouping construct establishing a precedence order (it also has impact on accessing matched substrings but that's a bit more of an advanced topic).  The regex `(abc)` will match the string "abc".

Answer (score 9):

`[a-z0-9]` will match any lowercase letter or number. `(a-z0-9)` will match the exact string `"a-z0-9"` and allows two additional things: You can apply modifiers like `*` and `?` and `+` to the whole group, and you can reference this match after the match with `$1` or `\1`. Not useful with your example, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try ([a-z0-9]) to capture a mixed string of lowercase letters and numbers, as well as capture for back references (or extraction).

Answer (score -2):

`[a-z0-9]` will match one of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789`.  In other words, square brackets match exactly one character.

`(a-z0-9)` will match two characters, the first is one of `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`, the second is one of `0123456789`, just as if the parenthesis weren't there.  The () will allow you to read exactly which characters were matched.  Parenthesis are also useful for OR'ing two expressions with the bar `|` character.  For example, `(a-z|0-9)` will match one character -- any of the lowercase alpha or digit.

Comment: Ranges only exist within character classes. `(a-z|0-9)` will match the string `a-z` or `0-9`, but not `a` or `5`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that clarification.  ([a-z]|[0-9]) would be more of what I described.