# How to improve the following python date regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am matching several formats of dates with this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uvdYVz/4).

`(?i)\b\d{1,2}[-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/](?:Ene|Enero|Feb|Febrero|Mar|Marzo|Abril|Mayo|May|Jun|Junio|Jul|Julio|Ago|Agosto|Sep|Sept|Septiembre|Oct|Octubre|Nov|Noviembre|Dic|Diciembre|\d+)[-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/](?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b`

However, I do not figure out how can add to the previous regex support for matching formats like this:

```
11 de Noviembre de 2013

23 de noviembre del 2011

11 de Noviembre del 2013
```

As you can see in the above regex, I tried to use `\w(\sde\s|\sdel\s)` and `(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)`. Nevertheless it is not working. How can I match the previous date cases?.

Comment: Why downvote?.... I provided an example and alternative approaches to solve this problem?... check the regex tester...

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/uvdYVz/5 Fixed it. You were using sets instead of capture groups for your de/del matching

Comment: It is very similar to what I tried.... why my attempt did not worked? @TemporalWolf

Comment: and regarding the downvote: I see no issues with your question - The only tip from the get go would be to include a copy of the regex, which you edited in. Other than that, it's a solid question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/]

[-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/]
```

is asking for [character classes `[]`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) when what you want is [groups `()`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (or non-capturing groups in this case) `(?:)`:

```
(?:-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/)

(?:-|–|—|\s|(?:\sde\s|\sdel\s)|\d+/)
```

see the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uvdYVz/5)

Additionally, if you're looking for a why:

[What's the difference between () and [] in regular expression patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789417/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-regular-expression-patterns)

Comment: Thanks... I thought `()` and `[]` were the same

Comment: @J.Do Nope. You should have read over the explanation at regex101.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Python question, why don't you remove the *de*'s and *del*'s as and when they occur by using

```
date = date.replace('de','').replace('del','')
```

And then operate on it as you were?

Comment: Then those aren't valid dates in terms of the langauge

Comment: Of course, I just can do a replace with a blank space.... but I am learning regex... I would like know how to capture specific strings...

Comment: _'Then those aren't valid dates in terms of the langauge'_ -- agree, but surely language specific constructs can be ignored in the internals of an application. You aren't sending the date stripped of the _de_ and _del_ to the user. 

That said however, it's perfectly understandable to want a regex based solution to this. I was just trying to play devil's advocate.