# How to make a Java regex match the longer word first

Tags: regex

My code is:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A|AB|ABC]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("ABC");
System.out.println(matcher.group());`
```

The Stdout output is:
A

But I want it to print "ABC" since ABC is the longest match.

Comment: Order of options matters. Reverse the order: `ABC|AB|A` or use `AB?C?`

Comment: Don't put it in `[]`. `[]` is a set, which, in your case, is saying *match a character present in the set `A|BC` because it's those characters literally

Comment: You'll want to use [greedy quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319840/greedy-vs-reluctant-vs-possessive-quantifiers).

Comment: @JohnEllmore how does that help

Comment: There was a typo in my original code.  ctwheels was correct. The order matters. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789417/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-regular-expression-patterns