# PDF matched incorrectly for image only href/src urls

Tags: regex

I am trying to get my regular expression to match any image url with certain optionals.
In my set that matches image file extensions everything is fine until I put in the `gif` extension. When I do that the `pdf` urls get matched for some reason.

Could anyone shed light on this?

I am using this within PHP with `preg_match_all` function

**Rules for matching**

1. Can be either src or href link
2. Can be relative or absolute link
3. Protocol can be http or https if given
4. Select only the link if matched
5. Case insensitive and global

**Pattern** (Take out gif and pdfs are skipped)

```
[src|href]="([(https|http):\/\/]?[^"]*.[jpg|png|jpeg|gif])"
```

**Test strings**

```
Should match <a href="http://blog.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.jpg">
Should match <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.jpg">
No match <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-somedoc.pdf"></a>
No match <a href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-somedoc.pdf"></a>
Should match <img href="http://blog.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.jpg"/>
Should match <img href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.gif"/>
Should match <img href="http://blog.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.jpg" />
Should match <img href="/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/13061-someimage.jpg" />
```

www.regex101.com fiddle: https://regex101.com/r/x3vVSx/1

Comment: You mixed up `[` and `(`, you want `(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)` instead of `[jpg|png|...]`. Similarly for `[src|href]`.

Comment: Grouping rather than classing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between () and \[\] in regular expression patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789417/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-regular-expression-patterns)

Comment: @Micha Wiedenmann Cheers, you can put that as an answer if you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Micha Wiedenmann for this.

Quote/Unquote

You mixed up [ and (, you want (jpg|png|jpeg|gif) instead of [jpg|png|...]. Similarly for [src|href].