# What is the regex for any number of spaces followed by one or more integers?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to make a regex which will match any string which looks like this: 
`User<spaces><Any positive integer here><spaces>Status:<anything here>`

Sample expression - `User 1 Status: Not Ready.`

Regex pattern - `^[User].*\d+.*[Status:].*$`

As you can see, I am using ".*" to incorrectly match spaces. I tried to use \s and [" "] instead, but they did not work. How do I handle spaces or tabs in this regex ?

By the way, I am using https://regex101.com/ with JavaScript regex parser to validate my Regex. I don't know if there is any nice regex helper website just for Java and not JavaScript.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `(User)` to capture "User" instead of using a character class which is denoted using `[]`. Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3789451/6785649) for details

Comment: `User\s*\d+\s*Status:.*`

Comment: [Asking for down vote reasons is not constructive.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/37123/148287) the only explanation/reason for a down vote you should ever expect is available if you hover over the down vote arrow. Someone's opinion is *This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* and they are under no obligation to justify their opinion and demanding one is just a form of passive-aggressive public shaming. Public shaming clearly violates the [*"Be Nice"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy.

Comment: Off-topic but how can I "hover" on my android phone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using character classes (those things surrounded by `[]`) inappropriately. The `[]`s don't mean "match these characters literally". They mean "match any one character in this list". For most characters, they themselves mean "match this literally".

Also, you seem to want to match `User:` in your regex, yet in the example you provided, there is no `:`, just `User`. Please decide whether or not you want the `:`.

`\s` is indeed used to match whitespace. You thought it didn't work probably because your regex has other mistakes, making the whole thing not match.

A corrected version of your regex:

```
^User\s*\d+\s*Status:.*$
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LGtFeb/1)

Comment: Nice answer. I find myself using regex a lot and have always used [<space><tab>] for whitespace. What are pros/cons of using \s? Readability, I suppose, but otherwise?

Comment: Don’t you want to match characters that are not spaces and tabs but are classified as white space as well? Like a full width space? Given the complexity of Unicode, there probably are many such characters. Plus, it’s another layer of abstraction and two fewer keystrokes.