# how to validate username input form JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
check 1st username input in given below link.
```

**https://vanillawebprojects.com/projects/form-validator/**

```
if you hit 3 space in input form

it still accepting username how can we prevent this?

js code link below.
```

**https://vanillawebprojects.com/projects/form-validator/script.js**

```
// Check Input Length
const checkLength = function (input, min, max) {
  if (input.value.length < min && input.value.trim() === '') {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be at least ${min} characters`
    );
  } else if (input.value.length > max) {
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`
    );
  } else {
    showSuccess(input);
  }
};
```

Comment: Please include the code that gives you problems in the question, and clearly state what exactly the problem is.

Comment: open the 1st link given above.
its accepting blank 3 spaces as username. 
i want to prevent that

Comment: On SO it's required to post code in the question. because that link may expire after some time, and then this question becomes useless for other readers.

Comment: I added code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const checkLength = function (input, min, max) {
  let input_value = input.value.trim();
  //var matches= input_value.match(/([\s]{3,})\1*/g);
  var matches= input_value.match(/[\s]{3,}/g);
  //THIS PATTERN WILL MATCH MORE THAN 3 WHITE SPACES
  
  if (input_value.length < min) { 
    // MINIMUM LENGTH ERROR MESSAGE
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be at least ${min} characters`
    );
  } else if (input_value.length > max) {
    // MAXIMUM LENGTH ERROR MESSAGE
    showError(
      input,
      `${getFieldName(input)} must be less than ${max} characters`
    );
  }
  else if(matches != null){
    console.log(`'${input_value}' WITH MORE THAN 2 WHITE SPACES`)
  }
  else {
    console.log(`'${input_value}' WITH LESS THAN 3 WHITE SPACES`);
  }
};



checkLength(document.getElementById('input_validate'),2,20);
checkLength(document.getElementById('input_validate2'),2,20);
```

```html
<input id="input_validate" value="BAAAD USER   NAME">
<input id="input_validate2" value="GOOD USER NAME">
```

I hope you got some idea

**EDIT**

I have updated regex as well

- \s matches whitespace
- {3,} wil match 3 or more than 3 characters (In your case whitespace)
- /g will match globally, ie. "BAD<first 3 whitespaces>USER<second 3 whitespaces>NAME", this input you will get two matches,1 afer BAD and other after USER
- The backreference \1 (backslash one) references the first capturing group. Here there is only one group (`([\s]{3,})`) which can be removed as per my second regex.

For more details, please refer [What's the difference between () and [] in regular expression patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789417/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-regular-expression-patterns)

**EDIT 2**

```js
let username_regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{0,1})*[0-9]+$/g;
var user_name = "USER NAM EA A12";
//THE ABOVE USER NAME WILL MATCH
console.log(user_name.match(username_regex))
var user_name = "USER NAME12A";
//THE ABOVE USER NAME WILL NOT MATCH BECAUSE IT ENDS WITH ALPHABET
console.log(user_name.match(username_regex))
var user_name = "12USER NAME12";
//THE ABOVE USER NAME WILL NOT MATCH BECAUSE IT START WITH NUMBERS
console.log(user_name.match(username_regex))
```

Comment: Can u explain what this regex doing here?
var matches= input_value.match(/([\s]{3,})\1*/g);
https://stackoverflow.com/users/11543253/rinshan-kolayil

Comment: and username should  not contain spaces or should no accept spaces in name.
bt here it accepting spaces between two words.

Comment: Can you please tell what characters you wish to use in the username, if you just want to remove whitespace simply use `if(input_value.indexOf(" ") !==-1){console.log("space exist");}else{console.log("space does not exist");}`;

Comment: it should be alphabetic character at beginning and at last it could be numbers.
i want it username input should not accept beginning and ending spaces, but it should only accept single space between two words.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/11543253/rinshan-kolayil

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not providing the code base.
I will try to answer from what generally acceptable for a username

You can use the method `trim`. Then you can test the string length

```
const greeting = '   Hello world!   ';

console.log(greeting);
// expected output: "   Hello world!   ";

console.log(greeting.trim());
// expected output: "Hello world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

If spaces between words are also undesired, you could create another function to validate the username, using a regex of the shape `'\s'` to find spaces in that username, if that returns true - the username is invalid.

Something like:

```
function validateUsername(value) {
   const regex = new RegExp('\s')
   return !regex.test(value)
}
```